# Spring SSE (SseEmitter): Flutter Client receiving events only after timeout

Tags: spring, flutter, spring-boot, server-sent-events

My Backend is developed in Spring Boot(2.7.0), Spring (5.3.20)
In my application I would like to stream data using Spring MVC Server-Sent-Events SSE: asynchronous server-to-client communication via http protocol

**Server-side:**

Subscription endpoint:
timeout is temporary set to 2 minutes

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ApiConstants.STREAM_API)@Validated
public class StreamingController {

    private final StreamingService service;

    @GetMapping(value = "/subscribe", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter subscribe() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(120000L); //Timeout 2 Minutes
        try {
            emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("INIT"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> service.getEmitters().remove(emitter));
        emitter.onTimeout(()-> service.getEmitters().remove(emitter));
        emitter.onError((ex)-> service.getEmitters().remove(emitter));
        service.getEmitters().add(emitter);
        return emitter;
  }
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class StreamingService {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<SseEmitter> emitters = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

}
```

Entity Listener class that sends an event after persisting a specific entity inthe database:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class EntityListener {

    private final StreamingService streamingService;

    @PostPersist
    protected void afterCreate(final Entity createdEntity) {
            List<SseEmitter> emitters = new ArrayList<>(streamingService.getEmitters());
            for (SseEmitter emitter : emitters) {
                try {
                    SseEmitter.SseEventBuilder event = SseEmitter.event()
                            .data("Last Score" + createdEntity.getScore())
                            .id(String.valueOf(createdEntity.getId()))
                            .name("Event Name");
                    emitter.send(event);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    emitter.completeWithError(ex);
                    streamingService.getEmitters().remove(emitter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client-side**

Flutter Code

```
print("Subscribing..");
Future<http.StreamedResponse>? response;

try {
    final _client = http.Client();

    var request = http.Request("GET", Uri.parse('http://localhost:5555/stream/subscribe'));
    
    Map<String, String> headers = {};
    headers.addAll(service.header);
    headers["Authorization"] = __token!;
    headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
    headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    response = _client.send(request);
    print("Subscribed!");
} catch (e) {
    print("Caught $e");
}

response?.asStream().listen((streamedResponse) {
    print("Received streamedResponse.statusCode:${streamedResponse.statusCode}");
    streamedResponse.stream.listen((data) {
        print("Received data:${utf8.decode(data)}");
    });
});
```

The problem is my Events aren't sent right after method send was called. They all come simultaneously (with same timestamp) to client only after timeout of SseEmitter.

Expected is that the Flutter listener receives the events in real-time

Answer (score 1):

You should probably verify your server configuration, or also nginx configuration if you are using it. And confirm that the headers of your request response contain this:

```
Content-Type: text/event-stream;
Cache-Control: no-cache;
X-Accel-Buffering: no;
```

Here is a good explanation of your issue : https://serverfault.com/questions/801628/for-server-sent-events-sse-what-nginx-proxy-configuration-is-appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little bit late but make sure the header **"Content-Encoding"** is not set to **gzip**, otherwise the payload will be sent when the stream is "complete".

ex:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/subscribe", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public SseEmitter subscribe(final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
   ...
   httpServletResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "");
   return emitter;
}
```